# Lifetime of a SqliteConnection

Tags: sqlite, .net-core, microsoft.data.sqlite

What is the recommended way of using a `SqliteConnection` object?
We are using sqlite inside a console application and I'm wondering if we should use a single connection for the entire application lifetime or create a new connection each time we need to query the data.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: There is in reality no recommended way - use it according to your needs. Generally with SQLite, if it doesn't matter, I recommend keeping hold of the connection, it's thread safe. There's some trivial overhead with connecting. If it's a shared cache db then at least one connection has to always be open anyway, so...